# R Pooled DataFrame analysis

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform several analysis on subsets of data in a dataframe in R, and i was wondering if there is generic way for doing this.

Say, I have a dataframe like:

```
       one two three four
 [1,]   1   6    11   16
 [2,]   2   7    12   17
 [3,]   3   8    11   18
 [4,]   4   9    11   19
 [5,]   5  10    15   20
```

how could I apply some computation (e.g. cumulative counting) based upon values in col "one" condition upon (grouped by) the value in col "three".

That is, I wanna do stuff to one column, based upon grouping in another column.  I can do this with loops, but I feel there might be standard ways to do this all at once.

thank you in advance!

Comment: I think i found something   ddply(data, .(coln), Stat).

Comment: You could use `aggregate`, with the formula notation, and the `subset=` optional parameter to set your condition (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186134/sum-by-factor-conditional-on-another-factor/22186348#22186348 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ddply(data, .(coln), Stat) does the trick exactly